# Multiples operaciones de excel con Python

Tags: python, excel

Tengo un archivo de excel donde guardo informacion, mas de 10,000 datos. Necesito poder realizar 1 cuenta masiva que se trata de una division entre dos celdas. El problema que tengo es que se hacerlo pero no para todos los datos. A esto me refiero que tengo todo el script hecho para 1 sola celda y necesito hacerlo para todas las que tengan datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La cuenta que tengo que hacer es `(D/E)*100`.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

doc = openpyxl.load_workbook(j)
a = doc.get_sheet_names()
a = a[9]

hoja = doc.get_sheet_by_name(a)

cell = hoja.cell(row=2, column=6)
cell.value ='=(D2/E2)*100'
```

Como muestra el ejemplo, solo hice la formula para la primer celda y ahora lo que necesito es para todas las celdas que tengan datos

Datos del xcel:

```
Cliente,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio,Impresiones_exchange,Subastas,Fill_rate,ECPM_medio
AAA,11,256,245825,0.607272727,0.443636364
BBB,9.37,258,5252,0.403636364,0.537272727
CCC,0.05,5282,5252,0.109090909,0.120909091
DDD,2.74,52,31660,12.66272727,0.640909091
EEE,18.94,241,536,3.167272727,0.831818182
FFF,0,0,0,0,0
GGG,0.23,4242,331680279,1.290909091,0.429090909
HHH,1.61,25,25363,0.636,0.742
iii,18.64,20,2525,1.328181818,0.478181818
JJJ,14.1,636,4569,5.964,0.148
KKK,0.12,428,253,2.794,0.32
LLL,2,125,469,0.280909091,0.36
MMM,0.34,310,22,0.826363636,1.049090909
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes también probar lo siguiente:

```
for i,cell in enumerate(hoja["D"],1):
    if i > 1:
       hoja["$G${0}".format(i)] = '=IF($E${0}=0,0,$D${0}/$E${0})'.format(i)
```

- Recorremos todas las celdas de la columna "D" (salvo la primera por si son los títulos)
- En la celda `G<n>` configuramos la formula. Nota que te agregué un `IF` a tu formula para evitarte el error por la división por 0.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar utilizando Pandas.

Defines antes tu función:

```
def funcion(fila):
    return (fila[0]/fila[1])*100
```

Imaginemos que "fila" es cada fila de tu excel. El valor [0] será el del campo 1 y el valor[1] del otro campo.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('nombre_del_archivo.xlsx')
df[nuevo_campo] = df[[campo1,otrocampo]].apply(lambda fila: funcion(fila), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar un loop `for`:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

doc = openpyxl.load_workbook(j)
a = doc.get_sheet_names()
a = a[9]

hoja = doc.get_sheet_by_name(a)

row_count = hoja.max_row

for i in range(2, row_count)
    cell = hoja.cell(row=i, column=6)
    D = hoja.cell(row=i, column=4)
    E = hoja.cell(row=i, column=5)
    if cell.value != None and E.value <> 0:
        cell.value = D.value/E.value*100
```

Comment: Tendría que ser más dinámico. En la pregunta el usuario especifica que son más de 10000, se podría calcular el número total de registros.

Comment: Esta bastante cerca pero me esta copiando '=(D2/E2)*100' en todas las celdas y yo lo que necesito es que en la celda numero 3 sea `'=(D3/E3)*100'`, en la 4 `'=(D4/E4)*100'` y asi hasta completar todas las celdas!

Comment: Lo probaste? porque me sale ahora `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Cell' and 'Cell'`

Comment: me es difícil probarlo porque no tengo mi pc :(. estoy suponiendo y respondiendo en la app. lo acabo de editar